# Changing point size in autocad

Tags: autocad

I don't know if its right forum. I'm posting question related to autocad. So please share link of forum (if I'm not allowed to ask it here)

How can I change point size (single point size 1/2/3) of point cloud (imported as pcg) in autocad.

Answer (score 2):

POINT Command

Creates a point object

Draw menu: Point

Command line:  point

Specify a point:

Points can act as nodes to which you can snap objects. You can specify a full three-dimensional location for a point. The current elevation is assumed if you omit the Z coordinate value.

The PDMODE and PDSIZE system variables control the appearance of point objects. PDMODE values 0, 2, 3, and 4 specify a figure to draw through the point. A value of 1 specifies that nothing is displayed.

Specifying the value 32, 64, or 96 selects a shape to draw around the point, in addition to the figure drawn through it:

PDSIZE controls the size of the point figures, except for PDMODE values 0 and 1. A setting of 0 generates the point at 5 percent of the drawing area height. A positive PDSIZE value specifies an absolute size for the point figures. A negative value is interpreted as a percentage of the viewport size. The size of all points is recalculated when the drawing is regenerated.

After you change PDMODE and PDSIZE, the appearance of existing points changes the next time AutoCAD regenerates the drawing.